# Text misaligned in multicolumn

Tags: multicol, multicolumn, text, alignment

I am trying to have part of the page divided into three columns and in each one a centered title and a description of different length. The problem is that the start of the bottom of the descriptions are misaligned, I am using the multicols package and \columnbreak between each. What should I change?

```
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{center}\textbf{Company 1}\end{center}
The company is based in XX, XX, the core business bla bla bla blaaaa bla bla. It is a public owned company where XXX XXX holds 100\% of the shares. Therefore its development is valuable for the municipality's growth strategy of the East area.
\columnbreak

\begin{center}\textbf{Company 2}\end{center}
The company is based in XXX, XXX, where produces bla bla blaaaaa blaaa, being one of the major worldwide producers of the latter one. It is part of the XXX Holding S.p.A. since XX. It directly provides XXX jobs, not to mention the indirect jobs and contractors \citep{blablabla}.
\columnbreak

\begin{center}\textbf{Material}\end{center}
The material exchanges in this synergy is the XXX XXX coming from the bla bla blaaaa blaaa. It is necessary in order to allow bla bla to be able to blaaaaa it, without this action, the blaaa would lose blaaa and the blaaaaa would get blaaa in it. It is reused in the xxx xxxx as raw material. Before this partnership the blaaa blaaaaa was collected and bla blaaa blaaa blaaaa.
\columnbreak

\end{multicols}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

You can use `paracol` instead of `multicol`; the package is precisely aimed to typeset text in independent columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry} % more generous line width
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{paracol}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{paracol}{3}
\sloppy
\begin{center}\textbf{Company 1}\end{center}
The company is based in XX, XX, the core business bla bla bla 
blaaaa bla bla. It is a public owned company where XXX XXX 
holds 100\% of the shares. Therefore its development is valuable 
for the municipality's growth strategy of the East area.
\switchcolumn

\begin{center}\textbf{Company 2}\end{center}
The company is based in XXX, XXX, where produces bla bla blaaaaa 
blaaa, being one of the major worldwide producers of the latter 
one. It is part of the XXX Holding S.p.A. since XX. It directly 
provides XXX jobs, not to mention the indirect jobs and contractors.
\switchcolumn

\begin{center}\textbf{Material}\end{center}
The material exchanges in this synergy is the XXX XXX coming from 
the bla bla blaaaa blaaa. It is necessary in order to allow bla 
bla to be able to blaaaaa it, without this action, the blaaa would 
lose blaaa and the blaaaaa would get blaaa in it. It is reused in 
the xxx xxxx as raw material. Before this partnership the blaaa 
blaaaaa was collected and bla blaaa blaaa blaaaa.
\end{paracol}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's always best to include a complete example code, from `\documentclass{whatever}` to `\end{document}`, because the effects you see may be caused by packages, definitions, etc. that are not part of your code fragment. However, I think you need `\raggedcolumns`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\raggedcolumns
\begin{center}\textbf{Company 1}\end{center}
The company is based in XX, XX, the core business bla bla bla blaaaa bla bla. It is a public owned company where XXX
 XXX holds 100\% of the shares. Therefore its development is valuable for the municipality's growth strategy of the
East area.
\columnbreak

\begin{center}\textbf{Company 2}\end{center}
The company is based in XXX, XXX, where produces bla bla blaaaaa blaaa, being one of the major worldwide producers of the latter one. It is part of the XXX Holding S.p.A. since XX. It directly provides XXX jobs, not to mention the indirect jobs and contractors \cite{blablabla}.
\columnbreak

\begin{center}\textbf{Material}\end{center}
The material exchanges in this synergy is the XXX XXX coming from the bla bla blaaaa blaaa. It is necessary in order to allow bla bla to be able to blaaaaa it, without this action, the blaaa would lose blaaa and the blaaaaa would get blaaa in it. It is reused in the xxx xxxx as raw material. Before this partnership the blaaa blaaaaa was collected and bla blaaa blaaa blaaaa.
\columnbreak

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: raggedcols]

Answer (score 2):

Using a `multicols` environment here might more than just a bit abusive. I recommend using three side-by-side `minipage` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\raggedbottom
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\textwidth}
\begin{center}\textbf{Company 1}\end{center}
The company is based in XX, XX, the core business bla bla bla blaaaa bla bla. It is a public owned company where XXX XXX holds 100\% of the shares. Therefore its development is valuable for the municipality's growth strategy of the East area.
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{\fill}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\textwidth}
\begin{center}\textbf{Company 2}\end{center}
The company is based in XXX, XXX, where produces bla bla blaaaaa blaaa, being one of the major worldwide producers of the latter one. It is part of the XXX Holding S.p.A. since XX. It directly provides XXX jobs, not to mention the indirect jobs and contractors \citep{blablabla}.
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{\fill}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\textwidth}
\begin{center}\textbf{Material}\end{center}
The material exchanges in this synergy is the XXX XXX coming from the bla bla blaaaa blaaa. It is necessary in order to allow bla bla to be able to blaaaaa it, without this action, the blaaa would lose blaaa and the blaaaaa would get blaaa in it. It is reused in the xxx xxxx as raw material. Before this partnership the blaaa blaaaaa was collected and bla blaaa blaaa blaaaa.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I propose using `tabularx` – more exactly `ltablex` which adds the functionalities of `longtable` to tabularx.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{ltablex} %brings the functionalities if longtable to tabularx
\usepackage{makecell}
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5\columnsep}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XXX@{}}
   \thead{Company 1}
 & \thead{Company 2}
 & \thead{Material}
 \medskip
 \endhead
The company is based in XX, XX, the core business bla bla bla blaaaa bla bla. It is a public owned company where XXX XXX holds 100\% of the shares. Therefore its development is valuable for the municipality's growth strategy of the East area.
&
The company is based in XXX, XXX, where produces bla bla blaaaaa blaaa, being one of the major worldwide producers of the latter one. It is part of the XXX Holding S.p.A. since XX. It directly provides XXX jobs, not to mention the indirect jobs and contractors \citep{blablabla}.
&
The material exchanges in this synergy is the XXX XXX coming from the bla bla blaaaa blaaa. It is necessary in order to allow bla bla to be able to blaaaaa it, without this action, the blaaa would lose blaaa and the blaaaaa would get blaaa in it. It is reused in the xxx xxxx as raw material. Before this partnership the blaaa blaaaaa was collected and bla blaaa blaaa blaaaa.
\end{tabularx}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]